# Understanding where generating fullchain.pem and privkey.pem fits into this cluster setup

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, tls1.2, hashicorp-vault

I used this repo https://github.com/scarolan/vault-aws-cf to generate a HashiCorp Vault and HashiCorp Consul cluster for secrets management. During the setup, it was required that the vault AMI's needed certificates, in this case a `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem`

What is their purpose in this setup? I generated a managed certificate for https on Amazon Web Services but want to understand the AMI server requirements for the certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those certs are used for your https listeners, for example [here](https://github.com/scarolan/vault-aws-cf/blob/29cbf3ab0aed555d1ccf6965dc1202e2d8823ddd/packer/scripts/install-vault.sh#L141).

The AWS certificates you generated through [AWS ACM](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) wont work since they are managed by AWS.

You could generated AWS certs through ACM, but you'd need access to the private key as well, for example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-export-private.html . That means that AWS wont be able to rotate your certs and you need to do it by hand.

You could also place your Vault behind an ALB and attach the certificates you generated in the first place in that ALB. This means that your SSL is terminated at the Load balancer level and the traffic between your ALB and Vault is going to be unencrypted.

Comment: thanks, this clears things up quite a bit. Novice question but as a test I used a self-signed certificate via openssl for the setup requirement and AWS ACM for the domain requirement.

Is the self-signed certificate something we will need to maintain every year?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by this `for the setup requirement and AWS ACM for the domain requirement` but if you used openssl, you will need to maintain the certs your self. If you are in AWS, you could add the certs/keys in SSM and have the ec2 fetch it on boot. That will make handling certs easier.